# how to unit test flutter without passing all mock classes explicitly?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, mockito

I am trying to find a way to mock a class without passing the mock version of it explicitly as a parameter via Providers. I just started to use Geolocator and I want to mock a couple of its functions, such as `getCurrentPosition`.

So far, I've passed the singletons via Providers so that I can mock them when I test the app. However Geolocator is a static class and when I try to *provide* it with a type, then it says:

`The return type 'Type' isn't a 'Geolocator', as required by the closure's context.`

The code looks like this:

```dart
Provider<Geolocator>(create: (context) => Geolocator)
```

The cleanest solution seems to be able to *inject*/*provide* that class without having to use `Provider`. However, then I can't pass the *MockGeolocator* either. So, what should I do?

Comment: Consider Riverpod, heir apparent to Provider.  Simplifies a lot, including mocking.

Comment: Does it have to be scoped to your widget tree? If not, maybe use another library such as get_it, which acts as a service locator, independent of the widget tree and context. Provider doesn't work well with abstract classes and inheritence